# Ocultando máscara de campo nulo Delphi

Tags: banco-de-dados, delphi, tabela-banco-de-dados

Eu tenho um campo DBText com informações de telefone, eu formatei o campo dessa forma "!99999-9999;1;_", só que quando aparece um campo nulo, ele acaba exibindo o hífen que separam os números, tem alguma forma de sumir com esse caractere, quando o campo for nulo?

Answer (score 0):

Use o evento `OnSetText`:

```
procedure TDM.cdsCadClientesFONESetText(Sender: TField; const Text: string);
begin
  if Text = '     -    ' then
    Sender.AsString := ''
  else
    Sender.AsString := Text;
end;
```